# Admin access mandatory for Sitecore Forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms, security

Is it mandatory for users to have admin access to be able to use the Sitecore Form Module?

I have a user with `Sitecore Client Authoring` role and `Analytics Maintaining` role, but the user is not able to see the Form Module in the Launchpad.

Is any other role specific to Forms required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-security-roles-in-sitecore-forms.html) you can put the user in the `Forms Editor` role. That should help.

The documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-security-roles.html) states for the Forms Editor role:

> Gives users access to the Sitecore Forms, Campaign Creator, and
> Marketing Control Panel applications from the Launchpad. The user can
> execute forms editing operations such as Edit Form, Rename Form, Move
> Form, and Delete Form.

Comment: Yes it worked, somehow the Forms Editor role was missing from my sitecore instance, got it from Vanilla.